# No Sound Toshiba Chromebook Dual Boot Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, chromebook, toshiba

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Toshiba Chromebook 2. It is a dual boot running alongside ChromeOS. I can not get any sound on Ubuntu (chrome works fine) and I have tried following some of the instructions that I have seen on other threads but to no avail. I am getting sound if I plug in headphones, but none out of the speakers. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Many thanks